# Unresponsive view instantiated with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

Im having some trouble with a view that I needed instantiating from a storyboard ID. In IOS simulator, the view loads with everything in place but is completely unresponsive. The date picker doesn't move and the buttons don't accept any interaction.

Ive checked the 'custom class' matches in IB and the Storyboard ID matches. The code is being executed in the PickerViewController because the UIDatePicker is being created in code and is correct and present in IOS simulator. Its just that nothing accepts any interaction. The buttons don't even go blue when touched.

I created the view in the previous view controller with:

```
PickerViewController *addViewController = (PickerViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view"];

[addViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];//chucked this line in to see if it helped


[addViewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[self presentViewController:addViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I'm not sure if this is a code problem, or if I've not hooked something up in IB properly. Any ideas??!!

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code. Check interfaceBuilder to see if you have a transparent view over your content or something like that.

Comment: No score. Ive had a load of grief before now getting the view to load in the first place. Im trying to get it to load when the user turns a UISwitch to on for some user settings stuff. The view started out life as a separate Xib but that that wasn't loading properly so I ended up adding it to the storyboard. It might just be one of those delete it, and copy and paste the code in again and it works problems!!

Answer (score 0):

Check your view controllers class in assistant editor:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. It now works after deleting the view and recreating it with a new view in IB with a new viewController. One of those xcode nuances!!!